# Catching all requests mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, http-request

I have a folder with resources and I'd like to give opportunity to all users with right token get access it.Requests like:

```
 www.mysite.com/uploads/images?token = some security value
```

So I need to handle all requests that starts with

```
 www.mysite.com/uploads
```

chek for right token and approve or reject request.Could you give a basic example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a route for `www.mysite.com/uploads/images/token`?

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Uploads", // Route name
            "uploads/images/{token}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "uploads", action = "images", token = "" } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

This route should be placed at top of your route list and would catch route that starts with `/uploads`... Your users would be routed to `uploadsController` (in this case) and would execute the `images` Action Method passing `Token` as a string parameter.